# How to expand abbreviations in datatable row by row c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable, abbreviation

I'm using datatable that has two columns of text data, I just want to do abbreviations expanding for each row, so I used Dictionary and here it is a sample of my code:

```
   private void ExpandWords()
    {    
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DataRow Row;
        DT.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        DT.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Label", typeof(string)));

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("emp", "employee");
        dict.Add("dep", "department");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView6.Rows.Count; i++)
        {   
            Row = DT.NewRow();
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> rep in dict)
            {
              Row[0] = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Replace    (rep.Key, rep.Value);
              Row[1] = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Replace  (rep.Key, rep.Value);
            }
        DT.Rows.Add(Row);
        dataGridView7.DataSource = DT;
     }
```

it can be run without exceptions but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you enumerate the dictionary in the loop of the grid-rows? Just lookup the key.

You also have to add each row in the loop, not outside, otherwise you just add the last row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView6.Rows.Count; i++)
{   
    Row = DT.NewRow();
    string abbrCell1 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string abbrCell2 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Row[0] = dict[abbrCell1];
    Row[1] = dict[abbrCell2];
    DT.Rows.Add(Row);
}
```

**Edit** If you want to replace all abbreviated words in the string of the datagrid cells with the not-abbreviated word in the dictionary you can use this code:

```
// in the loop
Row = DT.NewRow();
string abbrCell1 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string abbrCell2 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
IEnumerable<string> unabbrWords1 = abbrCell1.Split()
    .Select(w => dict.ContainsKey(w) ? dict[w] : w);
IEnumerable<string> unabbrWords2 = abbrCell2.Split()
    .Select(w => dict.ContainsKey(w) ? dict[w] : w);
Row[0] = string.Join(" ", unabbrWords1);
Row[1] = string.Join(" ", unabbrWords2);
DT.Rows.Add(Row);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Tim, actually every row has a string of words, I just want if a row has an abbreviation replace it using the dictionary

Comment: What means _"a row has a string of words"_? You have two columns and each column can contain a string which contains several words. One or more of these words can be abbreviated, is this correct? Now, you want to replace all of these abbreviated word in the string with the not-abbreviated word in the dictionary's value. Is this true? If so, you really should have mentioned these details(with sample data) in your question.

Comment: Yes Mr. Tim you got it, but I applied your code it just expand the abbreviations with the first postion

Comment: @user2102572: What means _"first position"_ in this context?

Comment: I mean it just expand the abbreviation that comes in the fist of the string

Comment: @user2102572: I doubt that. You should really provide sample data. Consider a string _"Btw, send me a sms if you're at home"_. If the dictionary contains `Btw -> by the way` and `SMS -> short message`. My approacch would replace nothing yet since i'm looking for the entire string not words. Btw, use `string.Split()` to split by words.

Comment: yes that's it Mr. Trim it works, the point was in checking if whether the string contains key or not

Comment: @user2102572: Note that i've changed the linq part above, there was a bug. Remember to accept the answer that answers your question. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it a bit otherwise you'll have same value overwritten in loop:

```
var value1 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
var value2 = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> rep in dict)
{
    value1 = value1.Replace(rep.Key, rep.Value);
    value2 = value2.Replace(rep.Key, rep.Value);
}

DT.Rows.Add(value1, value2);
```

You're also missing `DataBind()` if you're using Web Forms at the end

```
dataGridView7.DataSource = DT;
dataGridView7.DataBind();
```

mz

Comment: `DataGridView` is the winforms component, it has no `DataBind` method.

Comment: Ohh well, he did not mention anything about WinForms :-)